# How to list all issues on an Enterprise Github using PyGithub

Tags: python, github, github-api, issue-tracking, pygithub

I've got a quick question about (hopefully) making my code a lot more efficient. currently I have something like the following:

```
g = Github(base_url = "https://github.companyName.com/api/v3" ,login_or_token="my_token")

repos = g.get_repos()
for repo in repos:
    try:
        issues = repo.get_issues()
        for issue in issues:
            i+=1
            print(i)
```

This code is just proof that I can access each issue, and in this case, just add up how many there are. As you can imagine this code is very inefficient, and in my opinion, poorly written.

Is there some sort of function that will allow me to access all issues from all repos in the enterprise Github?  This would hopefully be similar to when you access all issues by going to the following link: https://github.companyName.com/issues.